# Quick new operator issue

Tags: c++

I know this is really easy and I'm looking over something but this is what I have...:

```
typedef struct
{
    char s1[81];
    char s2[81];
    char s3[81];
}Rec;

int main()
{   

   Rec *a[10];

   a[0] = (Rec*)new unsigned char(sizeof(Rec));
   a[0]->s1= "hello";
   printf("a[0] = %s\n",a[0]->s1);
   delete(a[0]);


   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Now, the line

> a[0]->s1= "hello";

is complaining about the expression must be a modifiable lvalue. I am pretty sure it's how I'm casting it in my new operator line and has it needs to be a long value or something but I'm not sure of the code to do this... easy i know but yeah. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What's with the old-school `typedef struct {...} Rec;` construct?

Comment: @John I swear, there's not enough emphasis placed on the differences between C and C++.

Comment: `new` is more powerful than `malloc`, use it accordingly: `a[0] = new Rec();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assign to char arrays like that.  Either use strcpy, or change your char arrays to `std::string`.

```
strcpy(a[0]->s1, "hello");
```

Why are you doing this:

```
a[0] = (Rec*)new unsigned char(sizeof(Rec));
```

instead of this:

```
a[0] = new Rec;
```

Comment: My guess is that he's done a lot of C, and simply replaced `malloc` with `new unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

Two things. The line

```
a[0] = (Rec*)new unsigned char(sizeof(Rec));
```

allocates a single `unsigned char` that gets initialized to the value `sizeof(Rec)`. You probably meant

```
a[0] = (Rec*)new unsigned char[sizeof(Rec)];
```

or better yet

```
a[0] = new Rec;
```

Second, you cannot assign a string literal to an array of chars, you need to copy the characters one by one, e.g.

```
char s[80];
s = "hello"; // won't work
strcpy(s, "hello"); // correct
```

You should however use `std::string` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you've done a lot of C in your life. Keep in mind that C++ is *different* language, which happen to share with C most of its syntax and some of its standard library. That means something that is perfectly fine in C might be quite ugly (or even dangerous) in C++.

With that said, let's rewrite your code in a more "C++-ish" way:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout, std::endl
#include <string> // std::string

struct Rec // typedef is implicit for structs in C++
{
    std::string s1; // use std::string instead of char arrays
    std::string s2;
    std::string s3;
}; // don't forget the semicolon!

int main()
{   

   Rec * a[10];

   a[0] = new Rec; // allocates the right amount of memory, no need to cast
   a[0]->s1 = "hello"; // std::sring handles the assignment for you
   std::cout << "a[0] = " << a[0]->s1 << std::endl; // use iostreams
   delete a[0]; // delete is an operator, not a function, no need for parentheses

   getchar(); // warning, this is not portable
   return 0;
}
```

As you see, `new` is not an "improved `malloc`". It's typesafe (no cast needed), it's safer to use (it allocates the exact amount of memory required, no need for `sizeof`), and it also does something that `malloc` *cannot* do: it invokes the class' constructor (just as `delete` invokes a destructor).

In C++, as in C, *allocation* is distinct from *initialization*. While in C you could just `memset` the block to zero, in C++ object construction can be a bit more complex. As such, you should *never* use `malloc` to create objects of classes that have non-trivial constructors (or have fields that don't have non trivial constructors - `Rec` is such a case). Because `new` always works, and has additional features, you should use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your casting. Your new expression allocates a single `unsigned char` and initializes it to the `sizeof(Rec)` instead of allocating enough space as `new unsigned char[sizeof(Rec)];` would do. That said, the types of `s1` and `"hello"` are different and you can't assign one with the other. You should be using something like `strcpy`, but since you tagged this **C++** then you would be better off using `std::string`. Also, why don't you just call `new Rec;`?

Answer (score 0):

a[0] is a pointer to an array of chars that can't be modified -- a[0] will always point to the same address.
you need to use strcpy to copy from your "hello" string to a[0]

Comment: `a[0]` is a pointer to Rec.  If you meant `a[0]->s1`, that is not a pointer to an array, it *is* an array.